# Parsing CSV fetched from Google Sheets

Tags: python, csv, http

I am trying to parse the CSV data fetched from a published Google Sheet.
I am fetching the CSV string with a simple http request.
Then trying to parse it with csv python library.
The parser seems not to be able to recognize the number of columns in each line but I don't understand how to fix it.

I tried the same code reading the csv from a disk file and it works perfectly.

```py
import csv
import requests

response = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vThbG2jdBjBWpcW0iarJD2TtW6olqygCvuQHRI-fwnLx6jkIFtuyiF7Bm4rEPLo_jpjLmZsr9sYGs8e/pub?output=csv&gid=784986591')
csv_bytestream = response.content.decode()
csv.register_dialect('GoogleDialect', delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
reader = csv.reader(csv_bytestream, dialect='GoogleDialect')
print(" **** NOT WORKING CODE **** ")
print(csv_bytestream)
num_row = 0
for row in reader:
    num_row += 1
    print("Row {num} has {nelem} columns".format(num=str(num_row) ,nelem=str(len(row))))
    print(row)

print(" **** WORKING CODE **** ")
with open('MyFile.csv','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read())

with open('MyFile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='GoogleDialect')
    num_row = 0
    for row in reader:
        num_row += 1
        print("Row {num} has {nelem} columns".format(num=str(num_row), nelem=str(len(row))))
        print(row)
```

I expect from both an output like:

```
Row 1 has 16 columns
['', 'Just insult, here and now!', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
Row 2 has 16 columns
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
...
```

While the output I get from the NON WORKING code is like:

```
Row 1 has 2 columns
['', '']
Row 2 has 1 columns
['Just insult, here and now!']
Row 3 has 2 columns
['', '']
...
```

The contents printed by the `print(csv_bytestream)` and the `print(f.read())` are identical.
I'd attach the csv file if I knew how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a string to the `csv` reader. Instead you should pass a file-like object or an interator returning lines.

You could either do:

```
import io
csv_bytestream = io.StringIO(response.content.decode())
```

or

```
csv_bytestream = response.content.decode().splitlines()
```

Note though that the variable `csv_bytestream` does not reflect the actual type of what you have as in the first case it would be returning text, not bytes, and in the second it would be lines.

Also note that instead of using `response.content.decode()` is better to use `response.text` as that will use the response's encoding.

Comment: "The problem is that you are passing a string to the csv reader. Instead you should pass a file-like object or an interator returning lines."
That was the part I was missing! Thanks!

Comment: confirmed here as well, `csv_bytestream = response.content.decode().splitlines()` was the correct approach to get this working! thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with encoding! The csv response that you are fetching has `ISO-8859-1`

```
 >>> response.encoding
 >>>'ISO-8859-1'
```

Here is working solution which might help you

```
response = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vThbG2jdBjBWpcW0iarJD2TtW6olqygCvuQHRI-fwnLx6jkIFtuyiF7Bm4rEPLo_jpjLmZsr9sYGs8e/pub?output=csv&gid=784986591')
csv_bytestream = response.content.decode('utf-8')
cr = csv.reader(csv_bytestream.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
my_list = list(cr)
my_list = list(cr)
for row in my_list:
    print(row)
```

Sample response:

```
['', 'Just insult, here and now!', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', 'STAGIONE CONTINUA', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', 'Rank', 'Adj', 'Player', 'Rating', 'Adj', 'Dist', 'Played', '# Pet', '% Pet/Played', '# Best', '# Worst', '(B-W)%', 'Wins', 'Losses', '']
['', '1', '⇔ (1)', 'JTsuited', '1674', '0', '0', '335', '4', '1,19%', '92', '52', '11,94%', '176', '159', 'HALL OF FAME']
['', '2', '⇔ (2)', 'Nameless', '1662', '2', '12', '293', '7', '2,39%', '74', '43', '10,58%', '171', '122', '']
['', '3', '⇑ (5)', 'Takysis', '1562', '55', '100', '688', '36', '5,23%', '145', '130', '2,18%', '348', '340', '']
['', '4', '⇓ (3)', 'Sfinks', '1528', '-19', '34', '696', '77', '11,06%', '134', '154', '-2,87%', '380', '316', '']
['', '5', '⇓ (4)', 'Neristelrooy', '1522', '-24', '6', '521', '37', '7,10%', '75', '103', '-5,37%', '282', '239', '']
['', '6', '⇔ (6)', 'Starmanzo', '1411', '-4', '111', '450', '24', '5,33%', '92', '78', '3,11%', '210', '240', '']
['', '7', '⇔ (7)', 'Bruno', '1386', '-13', '25', '446', '33', '7,40%', '74', '89', '-3,36%', '214', '232', 'HALL OF SHAME']
['', '8', '⇑ (9)', 'Biru', '1350', '-13', '36', '792', '132', '16,67%', '103', '159', '-7,07%', '414', '378', '']
['', '9', '⇓ (8)', 'Alino', '1340', '-32', '10', '33', '1', '3,03%', '3', '5', '-6,06%', '13', '20', '']
['', '10', '⇑ (12)', 'starpa', '1246', '48', '94', '796', '62', '7,79%', '177', '124', '6,66%', '337', '459', '']
['', '11', '⇓ (10)', 'Praxy', '1237', '0', '9', '223', '35', '15,70%', '30', '46', '-7,17%', '111', '112', '']
['', '12', '⇓ (11)', 'Beatren', '1218', '0', '19', '213', '19', '8,92%', '43', '43', '0,00%', '92', '121', '']
['', '13', '⇔ (13)', 'staratlas', '1169', '0', '49', '75', '9', '12,00%', '6', '22', '-21,33%', '34', '41', '']
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the encoding, the problem is that it is passing the whole csv to the reader, while yours is splitting the lines first.